# mysql logical "if then" on select

Tags: mysql, logical-operators

I have a table 'A' that look like that :

| L | S |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 0 |
| D | 1 |

And I want to add a new column U saying 'OK' or 'NOK' depending on following condition :

```
If A = 0 & B = 1 => Line A = NOK Else OK
If A = 1 & C = 1 => Line B = NOK Else OK
If B = 1 & D = 1 => Line C = NOK Else OK
```

So it should look like :

| L | S | U |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | OK |
| B | 1 | OK |
| C | 0 | NOK |
| D | 1 | OK |

I have tried with a CASE, but it is not working, I cannot do the "then C = NOK" when I'm in "If B"

```
SELECT A.*, 
    (
        CASE
                WHEN (L = 'A' AND S = 0) AND (L = 'B' AND S = 1) THEN "NOK"
                WHEN (L = 'A' AND S = 1) AND (L = 'C' AND S = 1) THEN "NOK"
                WHEN (L = 'B' AND S = 1) AND (L = 'D' AND S = 1) THEN "NOK" 
                ELSE 'OK'
        END
) AS `U`
FROM A
```

How can I achieve that in mysql directly ? Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a solution https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=37d00709de9bb19d4f6f2ec62c81bf22&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: unfortunatelly if is not what I need. Here it check only if S = 1. In my case, it is when B has S=1 AND D has S=1 THEN change the U value of C at "nok"

Comment: What's the error message that you're getting?